# Remembering One's Sins After Yom Kippur

Tags: sin, yom-kippur, repentance-teshuvah, tachanun

Should one remember and keep the guilt of his sins after Yom Kippur? If he had previously written them in a book, in order to have the proper mindset during tachanun throughout the year, should the book be destroyed or thrown away in tashlikh?

Extra: What should one do with evidence of sins that were recorded incidentally or by someone else?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

The Mechaber in Shulchan Aruch 607:4

> עונות שהתודה עליהם ביום הכפורים שעבר ולא שינה עליהם אפ"ה יכול לחזור ולהתודות עלי:4

> Regarding sins for which one confessed on the previous Yom Kippur and did not repeat, he may confess them again.

The Mishna Berura in 607:13,14

> אפ"ה יכול וכו' - אף בין אדם לחבירו גנב וגזל וכדומה אע"פ שמחל לו והשיב את הגזילה מ"מ מתודה ביוה"כ לעולם דמ"מ בין אדם למקום חטא אבל אם הקניט חבירו בדברים או עני המהפך בחררה י"ל כה"ג כיון שביקש מחילה מחבירו והתודה ביו"כ א' א"צ להתודות ביו"כ שנית [פמ"ג]:

> לחזור ולהתודות - ובגמרא קאמר הרי זה משובח משום שנאמר וחטאתי נגדי תמיד

So although one may stop asking for forgiveness after Yom Kippur, it's considered praiseworthy to continue asking if it is a sin between man and G-D